# Joomla DB query not executing properly

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm creating several custom components and when I delete an entry in one component, it will have to delete the entry with the same key in all the other components.

I thought I was smart and did the following so I don't have to rewrite the code for every single table. This used to work but now it stopped working and I can't figure out why. The main item gets deleted but all the other corresponding items stay put. I checked the database and all the values match up. Is there perhaps a way to check the full query joomla is executing? A print_r of `$query` gives me nothing readable.

```
public function deleteRecords($order_ids, $tables) {
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        foreach ($order_ids as $id) {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->delete($db->quoteName('#__' . $table));
            $query->where('order_id=' . $id->order_id);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            try {
                $result = $db->query();
            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Where `$order_ids` and `$tables` look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => modeling
    [1] => exo_product
    [2] => shoe_production
    [3] => order_status
    [4] => hikashop_order
)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [order_id] => 50
        )
)
```

I probably made some stupid mistake somewhere but I've been on it for 3 hours now and I can't get it to work :(

Comment: `print_r` won't give anything coherent in this case. Just `echo $query;` after `$db->setQuery($query)`. Using foreach for $order_ids worked for you before? It is an array with an associative array, no?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I was first deleting the main entry and THEN all the other ones. I swapped the order around and now it seems to work. I have no clue why. Perhaps the deleting function was being skipped after the main entry had been cleared or something.